# R - Subset a data frame (into multiple files) given IDs from multiple datasets

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Let G be my "master data frame" with multiple columns including "id".
Let S[i] be multiple files containing only 1 column = "id".

"id" in G and S[i] are the same.

I want to create H[i] which is a subset of G.
H[i] contains all columns in G BUT only observations in S[i] (or "ids" in S[i]).

Example:

G

```
id     x     y
1      1     3
2      1     4
3      2     6
4      3     4
5      4     5
6      4     1
```

S[1]

```
id
2
3
6
```

H[1] will be

```
id    x     y
2     1     4
3     2     6
6     4     1
```

Comment: where is G? H is supposed to be from G given i in S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an empty result list created called `H`, you can iterate through the items in `S` like so:

```
H <- list()

for(x in 1:length(S))
{
  H[[x]] <- subset(G, id %in% S[[x]]$id)
}
```

Comment: I let i=10.

I get the following:

[[1]]
[1] id   x y  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
.
.
.
.

[[10]]
[1] id   x y  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Not what I wanted. Was there anything in my question that need to be clarified?

Comment: what returns with `str(S[1])`?

Comment: > str(S[1])
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':       10 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ id: Factor w/ 10 levels "1329","1397",..: 6 4 5 7 10 8 9 2 3 1

Comment: OK: adjust the line within the for loop like so:
`H[[x]] <- subset(G, id %in% S[[x]]$id)`

Comment: Wow great. What just happened? How did str() help?

Comment: `str()` told me that your object `S` contained a list of data frames.  Knowing that `S` is a list means that the `S[[x]]` notation is appropriate for accessing those data frames instead of `S[x]`

Answer (score 0):

Consider `merge` inside `lapply`:

```
H <- lapply(S, function(x) merge(G, x, by="id"))
```